# Cannot establish a secure A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception while recording a native app using loadrunner

Tags: ssl, performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner

We are using Load Runner 12.50 .

While recording the native app  using proxy mode , am getting error message

stating "**Cannot establish a secure 
connection to the client, message=A call to SSPI failed, see inner 
exception."**

Due to this error , scripts are not recorded in Actions

Can anybody please help us how solve this error . So their any setting which

need to be done under Load Runner .

Thanks,

Prabhakar.Y

Comment: Define "native app" in your context.  A native Windows application?  Does the application use HTTP as the communications mechanism?

Comment: @James,native mobile app which uses HTTP as it protocol for communication. Am using mobile protocol HTTP/HTML with proxy recording am not able to  record the business process in load runner. It shows [Proxy Recording.Error (1b84:1cc4)] Cannot establish a secure 
connection to the client, message=A call to SSPI failed, see inner 
exception.[Proxy Recording  (1b84:1c10)] Client request from @ IP addr

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the proxy on the handheld to connect to the PC running VUGEN?  If not, you may have a firewall rule either on the local PC set by group policy object or within your network infrastructure which is preventing this communication.  This is the most common reason why you cannot record in proxy mode.

Comment: yes am able to set the proxy running vugen and device. The exact problem what we are facing is that the app which is under our test env we are not able to record the transactions however the app which is present in app we are able to record transactions . And we do have deployed in Amazon servers those apps are recorded but the app which is locally deployed we are not to able to record as it states "Cannot establish a secure connection to the client, message=A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception." . We had discussed with dev team they also not sure why this happens. Plz help us

Comment: Use a control application or site, such as prod or another site, such as Google, to see if you have the same issues.   This is using the second site as a control issue to check for issues on your installation versus issues with your application